# Trouble accessing items in an array of arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

```
let arrayOfDwarfArrays = [["Sleepy", "Grumpy", "Doc"], ["Thorin", "Nori"]]

var dwarfArray: [String] = []
for dwarfName in arrayOfDwarfArrays {
    dwarfArray.append(dwarfName)
}
```

All I'm trying to do is access the values of the original array of arrays and append them to a new, single array. But I keep getting this error:

Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'

In the simplest of terms, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's happened because `dwarfArray` is an array of string and expecting a string to be appended. However, it's getting an array of string instead of just string.

Try like this

```
let arrayOfDwarfArrays = [["Sleepy", "Grumpy", "Doc"], ["Thorin", "Nori"]]

var dwarfArray: [String] = []
for dwarfName in arrayOfDwarfArrays {
    dwarfArray.append(contentsOf: dwarfName)
}
```

Comment: Technically correct, but it's *much* better to just use `append(contentsOf:)`. For one, it does only resize operation, whereas this code can do any number of resizes.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.append(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126937-append) expects an argument of type `Element`, which is only a single element. Obviously, providing a `[String]` as an argument to this parameter would only work if `Element` is `[String]`, i.e. if the array had type `[[String]]`. Since this isn't the case, `Array.append(_:)` is not the right choice.

Instead, you should use [`Array.append(contentsOf:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126939-append), which expects an argument of type `S`, where `S` is any `Sequence` conforming type whose `Element` is the same as the Array's element. This is suitable for when you want to append all of the elements of a subarray (dwarfName).

```
let arrayOfDwarfArrays = [["Sleepy", "Grumpy", "Doc"], ["Thorin", "Nori"]]

var dwarfArray: [String] = []
for dwarfName in arrayOfDwarfArrays {
    dwarfArray.append(contentsOf: dwarfName)
}
```

In this particular case though, this code is even better expressed using a simple [`Array.flatMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126947-flatmap) operation:

```
let arrayOfDwarfArrays = [["Sleepy", "Grumpy", "Doc"], ["Thorin", "Nori"]]
let dwarfArray = arrayOfDwarfArrays.flatMap { $0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel. You can use a Sequence [instance method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2431985-joined) called `joined()`. It will return a `FlattenCollection<[[String]]>` which you can use to initialise a new array if needed:

```
let dwarfCollections = [["Sleepy", "Grumpy", "Doc"], ["Thorin", "Nori"]]

// Use 'joined()' to access each element of each collection:
for dwarf in dwarfCollections.joined() {
    print(dwarf)
}
```

If you need to create a new array just initialize it with the elements of the flatten collection:

```
let dwarfs = Array(dwarfCollections.joined())  // ["Sleepy", "Grumpy", "Doc", "Thorin", "Nori"]
print(dwarfs)
```

This will print

> Sleepy
>
> Grumpy
>
> Doc
>
> Thorin
>
> Nori
>
> ["Sleepy", "Grumpy", "Doc", "Thorin", "Nori"]